# PostgreSQL Drop Unique Index

Tags: postgresql, flyway

I have this statement in Postgres to create a unique index: 
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY organization_user_ux1 ON organization_user (organization_id,user_id);

... I need to drop this unique index, so I tried:

ALTER TABLE public.organization_user
  DROP INDEX organization_user_ux1;

and recieved error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "organization_user_ux1"
 using flyway to execute these scripts.

How do I correctly undo this concurrent unique index?

Answer (score 1):

Read This documentation for your reference [Drop Index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-dropindex.html)

IN your case :

```
DROP INDEX organization_user_ux1
```

or if you want it concurrently

```
DROP INDEX CONCURRENTLY organization_user_ux1
```

Comment: @MaxMilovets  All supported versions of PostgreSQL support `drop index concurrently`.  If you are using a version so ancient that it does not, you should 1) upgrade urgently, 2) tell us the version, 3) not use features unsupported on the ancient version.